# MySQL function giving wrong value

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a search engine whereby I require videos to be displayed according to the keywords input.

So for my codes, I have

```
$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);
            foreach($search_exploded as $search_each){
                $x = 0; 
                $x++;

                if($x>=1){
                    $construct ="keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
                }

                else{
                    $construct ="OR keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";

                }
                $x = 0;
            }
```

and

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM test WHERE $construct";

                    $runquery = mysql_query($query);

                    $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($runquery);
```

The problem lies in the $runquery as my the error i get from my browser states that the line `$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($runquery);` is returning a Boolean value instead of the supposed resource type value.

Can anyone help fix this? I'm stuck on this for quite some time now. Thankful for and appreciate  any help!

Comment: You have a issue in your foreach.. You are resetting it each time you run through it, meaning it will always be 1. - also, your `$construct ` is reset to the latest value each time it's run through the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a problem in if condition and every time you set $x to 0 , then why you init it.

```
   $x = 0;
  foreach($search_exploded as $search_each){               
           if($x==0){ 
                $construct =" keywords LIKE '%$search_each%' ";
            }else{
                $construct .=" OR keywords LIKE '%$search_each%' ";
            }
            $x++;
        }
```

Try this .

Comment: $construct .="OR..." maybe no ?

Comment: yes,
   $construct .=" OR keywords LIKE '%$search_each%' ";

Comment: Just a small thing if you care, but there is no need for spaces in both ends of the `$construct` ends, it's enough with one in either end.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of logical errors inside your `foreach` loop pertaining to the `$x` variable.

Here is a simple way to achieve what you are trying to do (without using some kind of flags like `$x`)-

```
$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

// An array for the `LIKE` conditions
$construct_list = [];

// Adding the conditions in the array
foreach($search_exploded as $search_each){
    $construct_list[] = "keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
}

// Joining them using OR
$construct = implode(" OR ", $construct_list);

// Supposing there are no keywords, the
// WHERE should not exist. So make a separate var for that - 
$where_clause = "";
if(trim($construct) != ""){
    $where_clause = "WHERE $construct";
}

// Perform your query
$query ="SELECT * FROM test $where_clause";
```

Comment: Great, this worked out for me! Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            $search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);
            $construct = '1';
            if (!empty($search_exploded)) {
                $construct = '';
                foreach($search_exploded as $search_each){
                    $construct .= $construct == '' ? " keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'" : " OR keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
                }
            }
            $query ="SELECT * FROM test WHERE $construct";

            $runquery = mysql_query($query);
            if ($runquery) {
                $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($runquery);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to try to omit the OR for the 2nd and subsequent runs around the loop, but keep it for the first. should be the other way round,.

But I would probably avoid using the loop, and just use implode. Something like this (although would need to escape the values before using them in the query).

```
$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

if (count($search_exploded) > 0)
{

    $construct = implode("%' OR keywords LIKE '%", $search_exploded);

    $query ="SELECT * FROM test WHERE keywords LIKE '%".$construct."%'";

    $runquery = mysql_query($query);

    $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($runquery);

}
```